# JS promise. Some node js and passport js. How can I get an internal structure from promise { {} }? req.user

Tags: javascript, node.js, passport.js

I can't get an item from req.user, when I try to see what's in req.user, it displays:

```
Promise {
  {
    login: 'login',
    password: '$2b$10$sivL/8KvPYzlN/b24nWNOOa7pd02WX',
    id: 12,
    role: 'user'
  }
}
```

It turns out that I can output Promise { {} }, but I only need the internal structure, how can I get it for further processing (take for example only the role)?

`req.user` is sets there (According to the guide)

```
const LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt')

function initialize(passport, getUserByEmail, getUserById) {
  const authenticateUser = async (email, password, done) => {
    const user = await getUserByEmail(email)
    if (user == null) {
      return done(null, false, { message: 'No user with that email' })
    }

    try {
      if (await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password)) {
        return done(null, user)
      } else {
        return done(null, false, { message: 'Password incorrect' })
      }
    } catch (e) {
      return done(e)
    }
  }

  passport.use(new LocalStrategy({ usernameField: 'email' }, authenticateUser))
  passport.serializeUser((user, done) => done(null, user.id))
  passport.deserializeUser((id, done) => {
    return done(null, getUserById(id))
  })
}

module.exports = initialize
```

Comment: You should resolve the promise, not try to extract the data from it directly.

Comment: Can you post the login function where `req.user` is set? You should be resolving the promise there and setting `req.user` with the result

Comment: You are not meant to look at the internals of promises - their internals are intentionally private.  If you want the resolved value of a promise, you use `.then()` or `await` on the promise and get the resolved value that way.  People could help you more specifically if you show where this object comes from (how it gets assigned to `req.user` in the first place.  That's probably where the code needs to be modified.

Comment: @coagmano Edited

Comment: @n33t thanks. Turns out my first guess was wrong, so I've edited my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: After seeing your strategy, I can see the issue is in `deserializeUser`. It looks like `getUserById` returns a promise, so you need to get the result first:

```
  passport.deserializeUser(async (id, done) => {
    const user = await getUserById(id);
    return done(null, user);
  })
```

---

Previous answer in case it helps someone else:

Your issue is most likely in your login strategy and not where you want to consume `req.user`.

Assuming you're using the LocalStrategy for passport, you return the final resolved user record in the callback like so:

```
passport.use(new LocalStrategy(
  function(username, password, done) {
    // Example service returning a promise
    UserService.loginWithPassword({ username, password }.then((user) => {
      if (!user) return done(null, false);
      return done(null, user);
    }).catch(error => {
      return done(err);
    });
  }
));
```

If you don't resolve the promise with `await` or `then`, you will end up with a promise for `req.user` like you have in your question:

```
passport.use(new LocalStrategy(
  function(username, password, done) {
    // Example service returning a promise
    const user = UserService.loginWithPassword({ username, password });
    // user will always be a promise here
    if (!user) return done(null, false);
    return done(null, user);
    // now `req.user` is the promise, instead of the user object
  }
));
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it works

Comment: @n33t Glad to help. Welcome to StackOverflow! While you're here, I encourage you to take the [tour of the site](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Thank you again, I will definitely pass :)